# .replace in VB VSTO add in for Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, visual-studio, vsto

I'm trying to search an excel workbook for specific char values and replace them with other char values.
I am able to do this in VBA in Excel, but I am trying to code an add-in in VS 2017 with VSTO.

My VBA code, which works is:

```
Sub charFix(control As IRibbonControl)

Cells.Replace What:="^", Replacement:=Chr(11), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Cells.Replace What:=Chr(10), Replacement:=Chr(11), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Cells.Replace What:=Chr(13), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

This is how I am trying to do it, and it is pretty wrong, haha.  But i'm not getting compile errors, so I'm lost.

```
Private Sub charKill_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles charKill.Click

        Dim ActiveWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet =
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet =
            Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(ActiveWorkSheet)
        Dim cellA1 As Excel.Range = ActiveWorkSheet.replace(Chr(10), Chr(11), Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, False, , False, False)

End Sub
```

I'm certain that everything before the 3rd Dim statement is correct, and I'm certain that everything from .replace, on is correct...I think the issue is how I'm trying to call it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to show more effort, rather than here is my working VBA code, now what would it look like in VB.NET, what have you tried so far? add your vb.net code you have tried to your question.

Comment: No, add your code to your question as its to do with your original post

Comment: essentially i'm trying to use the same package that excel uses for it's find and replace in vba in vb.net via vsto in visual studio, but I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: You mentioned you are getting errors, what are the errors? Add them to your question.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, it's just crashing excel.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub charKill_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles charKill.Click

    Dim activeWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet =
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim workSheet As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet =
        Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(activeWorkSheet)
    Dim workRange As Excel.Range = workSheet.Cells

    workRange.Replace(vbLf, vbVerticalTab, SearchOrder:=2, MatchCase:=True)
    workRange.Replace("^", vbVerticalTab, SearchOrder:=2, MatchCase:=True)
    workRange.Replace(vbCr, "", SearchOrder:=2, MatchCase:=True)

End Sub
```